# Joist tape needed for ground contact joists / beams?

Tags: framing, deck, waterproofing, joists

If using ground contact timbers and joists for the structure of a deck (in this case a treehouse), is it a good idea to use joist tape to help protect against rot over the course of many years, or does it being ground contact render it not helpful.

Comment: What is "joist tape"? Are you using it on portions where the wood touches the ground or just in general? Please [edit] to provide some more clarity.

Comment: Huh... [apparently](https://www.decks.com/how-to/articles/joist-tape-what-is-it-and-do-i-need-it) joist tape is sticky flashing applied to the tops of joists to protect against water infiltration and seal around screw holes. TBH, it sounds like a marketer's dream product - use the same kind of sealant tape designed to seal doors & window flashing and come up with a new use for it. IMHO, it'd be optional in all deck installations, but I'd wait for someone with more experience to chime in.

Comment: Also, just stumbled across this [highly related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158971/protecting-the-tops-of-deck-joists-or-not).